# Neural Net and genetic algorithms

Tags: algorithm, genetic

I am trying to play around with neural net and genetic algorithms, but I have problems.

So the task is pretty simple:
I have moving circles and if they stay in the picture longer than others their fitnesses are better than the other ones.

My approach is:

1. Take the top 3 scorer
2. Create an array with 100 items, where the amount an scorer gets, depends on the percentage fitness score of the top 3
3. Choose a random gen-pool and cross it with another random (of the top3)
4. Mutate

All the crossover and the mutation only changes the weights for the neurons and the given inputs.

Now the question is:

Is there any chance, I will get any good results with these approach?

Even if i just copy the best one to replace all 20 new players, they keep getting worse (with some small "Superman" in between)

Can I even approach this problem this way, or shouldn't I mix these two methods?

Edit: This is my crossover method, which basically generates a random number to choose the amount of weights that are copied from one neuron, until it switches to the other one.

```
def crossover(gen_1, gen_2, neuron):
    new_genes = dict()
    limit = random.randint(0, len(Definitions.array_index)-1)
    for x in range(0, limit):
        new_genes[Definitions.array_index[x]] = gen_1.neuron[neuron].weights[Definitions.array_index[x]]
    for x in range(limit, len(Definitions.array_index)):
        new_genes[Definitions.array_index[x]] = gen_2.neuron[neuron].weights[Definitions.array_index[x]]
    return new_genes
```

Comment: "even if i just copy the best one to replace all 20 new players, they keep getting worse" Sounds like a problem with your code then, maybe creating a new reference to vs. a copy of an array. Hard to say without code.

Comment: This question is not related to programming. I think it is off-topic. I think you'll have more luck in the Artificial intelligence StackExchange forum

Comment: Ok so i found out why there where still acting as if they were learning, but they still keep getting worse :/ But at least now they all do kinda the same :)

Comment: I think the question _is_ related to programming, but we're in the dark.